# Error in android apps development in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

During android application development in eclipse when I am going to create AVD an error is coming  [2014-03-10 09:37:27 - SDK Manager] Error: Error parsing C:\Users\Pallabi.android\devices.xml, backing up to C:\Users\Pallabi.android\devices.xml.old - How to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

try clean up your eclipse

```
./eclipse -clean
```

or

```
assign your android SDK to correct path in local.properties

# This file is automatically generated by Android Tools.
# Do not modify this file -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE ERASED!
#
# This file must *NOT* be checked into Version Control Systems,
# as it contains information specific to your local configuration.

# location of the SDK. This is only used by Ant
# For customization when using a Version Control System, please read the
# header note.
sdk.dir=/Applications/android-sdk
```